# AWS ElastiCache Describe CacheClusters

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to run the [describe_cache_clusters](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticache.html#ElastiCache.Client.describe_cache_clustershttp://) command on Python using boto3. This command works when my ElastiCache Cluster has one node, but it does not work when there are multiple nodes. I get the same error as well when I use the AWS CLI command which is that the cluster is not found.

```
    client = boto3.client('elasticache')
    paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_cache_clusters')
    response = paginator.paginate(
    CacheClusterId='xxxxx',
    ShowCacheNodeInfo=True,
    ShowCacheClustersNotInReplicationGroups=False,)
```

Is this a shortcoming of the function itself? I am trying to get the cachecluster endpoint without having to use the UI.

Here are some of the ElastiCache configuration:

```
Redis: 3.2.4
NodeType cache.r3.large
1 Shard, 3 Nodes
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem. Since there are multiple nodes I need a -001 (or2,3,) in the cachecluseterid. Then the function works

Comment: or use `ReplicationGroupId` but that is not a distinct resource, more of a property.